# Using filtering in Shared Dashboard with KQL

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to add some functionality via a Shared Dashboard using my telemetry logged to application insights,

This query gives me the desired result rendered in a barchart, when I apply filters for the customDimensions of `FileName` and `Name` and apply `take 25` it renders great and shows me the 25 slowest invocations of a particular durable azure function with the operation id as the y-axis and the computed duration (ms) on the x-axis

[image: Example]
[image: Example 2]

```
customEvents
| extend FileName = tostring(customDimensions["FileName"])
| extend Name = tostring(customDimensions["Name"])
| extend OperationId = operation_Id
| summarize Duration=datetime_diff('millisecond', max(timestamp), min(timestamp)) by OperationId, Name, FileName
| order by Duration desc
| render barchart with (xtitle="Operation Id", ytitle="Duration (ms)", legend=hidden)
```

When I try to add this same query (without the Where clauses) to a Shared Dashboard, I then go to apply the same filters of FileName, Name and I see different results.

1. I am not able to apply `take 25` as that limits the `FileName` available for me to chose from over a 30 day period
2. As I select `FileName` and `Name` I can see the graph changes but when I go to select a `OperationId` the list total remains the same and does not filter based on the previous inputs

[image: Shared Dashboard]
[image: Shared Dashboard Query]

How can I replicate the same results as in the first image shown where I am querying with provided `FileName` and `Name` and take only a subset (first 25) - while still being able to apply filters in a Shared Dashboard?

I have tried using a Workbook but unfortunately these queries compiled from appinsights log query appear different and you are unable to hide things like legends, etc. so it is not desirable

Answer (score 1):

> How can I replicate the same results as in the first image shown where I am querying with provided `FileName` and `Name` and take only a subset (first 25) - while still being able to apply filters in a Shared Dashboard?

> 1. I am not able to apply  `take 25`  as that limits the  `FileName`  available for me to choose from over a 30-day period

I have noticed that in your query you are collecting all information while using extend.

Using the same query which you have used
[image]

Filtering 25 values of the overall result
[image]

Results in Shared Dashboard
[image]

> 2. As I select  `FileName`  and  `Name`  I can see the graph changes but when I go to select a  `OperationId`  the list total remains the same and does not filter based on the previous inputs

You can use **`${Filter_Name }`** to dynamically use filter value in your query.

Eg:

```
Event | where ${Computers} | summarize count() by EventLevelName
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I am unable to reference dynamic filters when I go to edit the log query directly in the Shared dashboard. i.e. customEvents | where customDimensions["FileName"] == ${FileName} -> dIsplays "Query could not be parsed at '{' on line [2,40] Token: { Line: 2 Position: 40". How would I add a variable of ${Filter_Name} or ${Computers} as you suggested to my Shared dashboard so that I am able to "Apply" my log query change?